# how can I get the current user's id (In an asp.net/c# website)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an `asp.net/c#` website where I use form authentication, I'd like to relate a certain type of content with the user who created it.

For this I'd like to access the current logged in user's id, so that i can pass it to the database as a foreign key.

There is an id column in the `"my_aspnet_users"` table that vs auto creates, but I could not find it in the User or Profile object's properties.

how can I access this property??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to query your database for any extra user info you need. Forms authentication doesn't know anything about user id's, or whatever primary key you use for your user table.

Presumably you're storing the username in the cookie, which is available to you in User.Identity.Name. Just look up the user in the database by username. You could also store the user id in the authentication cookie.

Comment: thank you. do you know the logic behind not putting the id as a property of the User object?

Comment: Probably because (a) the name is more display-friendly, and (b) MS didn't want to dictate the id type (int, Guid, etc.).

Comment: Agree with Tuan. It helps to view most of these properties, like usernames and user id's, as belonging to a more general concept. Authentication requires a way to uniquely identify someone. Whether that's through a username, an email address, a Guid, an integer, their Facebook ID if you're authenticating users via Facebook, whatever. Forms authentication let's you use _something_ to uniquely identify the user, it just so happens it usually ends up being their username. Don't view the User.Identity property as having anything to do with your user table.

Comment: Sorry for two comments. You could add an authentication cookie for someone that isn't even registered. User.Identity.Name gives you access to whatever you put in FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username"). In other words, if you did FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("1234"), User.Identity.Name would hold 1234.